# Dimension of quotient vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A doubt: let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $p(x) \in k[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$ without repeated roots. The quotient $k[x]/(p(x))$ is isomorphic, as a vector space, to $k^{n}$ right? because we can factor $p(x)$ as a product of linear factors and then use the chinese remainder theorem. Is this correct?

Comment: To use the chinese remainder theorem, the factors needs to be comaximal. If $p(x) = (x - a)^n$, then each of the factors are not comaximal. If $p(x)$ is separable, then this is true.

Comment: @William: just added that $f$ has no repeated roots.

Comment: In that case, yes.

Comment: Correct. But **as a vector space** $k[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $k^n$ irrespective of whether $p(x)$ has repeated factors and irrespective of whether $k$ is algebraically closed. This is because each coset has a unique polynomial of degree $<n$ in it, and those form a vector space od dimension $n$.

Comment: Also note that $k[x] \slash (p(x))$ is thought of as a quotient of rings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether $p(x)$ is squarefree or not, and whether $k$ is algebraically closed or not, $k[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ has dimension $\deg(p)$: this follows from the division algorithm.

If $k$ is algebraically closed and $p(x)$ is squarefree, then you actually get that $k[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $k^n$ *as rings*: the map into the product is a ring homomorphism.

For general $k$ and $p(x)$ squarefree, you get a product of extensions of $k$, and again an isomorphism as rings.